Angular Component Not Subscribing to Service Observable
I have an Angular component that is supposed to react to changes emitted by an observable in a service, but it doesn't seem to be subscribing or reacting as expected. I'm working in the front-end part of a project in Angular, where I've created a tutorial using the ngx-joyride library. The tutorial works fine but now I need to show a component after executing step number six. The thing is in this web-page you can create different platforms but when you start the tutorial there is no platform displayed and my objective is to display one hard coded (using a dynamic component tutorial-platform.component). For that I'm using an observable to where I want to subscribe.
Here’s a summary of what I’ve done so far:
This is my tutorial.service.ts, the service that controls the tutorial and the one where I've created my observable:

// tutorial.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JoyrideService } from 'ngx-joyride';
import { PlatformsService } from './platforms.service';
import { PlatformsComponent } from '../platforms.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TutorialService {
  private currentStep: string = '0';
  // I create an instance 'Subject'
  private displayFakePlatformSubject = new Subject<void>();
  // I convert the 'Subject' in an 'Observable'
  displayFakePlatform$ = this.displayFakePlatformSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private joyrideService: JoyrideService,
    private router: Router,
    private platformsService: PlatformsService,
  ) { }

  // Some more functions
  
  // Function to listen to an event
  fakePlatformDisplay() {
    console.log('entering fakePlatformDisplay()...');
    this.displayFakePlatformSubject.next();
  }
}

Now we are going to see the 6th step of the tutorial to se how we make the call to the function(dyd.component.html), and the function that calls next button is defined in dyd.component.ts:
HTML
<div class="back-btn-div">
    <ng-template #prevButton>
      <button nbButton (click)="onPreviousStep()">Previous</button>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #nextButton>
      <button nbButton (click)="onNextStep()">Next</button>
    </ng-template>
    <button (click)="openBackWindow()"
    (next)="7"
    joyrideStep="6"
    title="Next step"
    stepPosition="bottom-end"
    [prevTemplate]="prevButton"
    [nextTemplate]="nextButton"
    ></button>
  </div>

TS
import { TutorialService } from "../platforms/services/tutorial.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'dyd-platforms',
    templateUrl: './dyd.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dyd.component.scss']
})

export class DydComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
        private tutorialService: TutorialService
    ) { }
  
    onNextStep() {
        let url: string;
        const currentStep = this.tutorialService.getCurrentStep();
        if (currentStep == '6') {
            url = '/platforms';
            console.log('Fake Platform has been displayed.');
            this.tutorialService.fakePlatformDisplay();
            console.log('-----------<>----------.');
        }
        else {url = '/editor';}
        const nextStep = (parseInt(currentStep) + 1).toString();
        this.tutorialService.navigateToStep(nextStep, url);
    }
}

So as you can see in the html when pressing the next button we call the ts function onNextStep() and this function calls the tutorialService.fakePlatformDisplay() we mentioned before.
When pressing the button we also move to the next step, that in this case is in another component (platforms.component), this is the component where we want to show our dynamic component. So first I'm going to show the dynamic component:
tutorial-platform.component.html
<div class="card-row">
  <div class="card-col">
    <div>
      <nb-card size="small" class="platformListCard">
        <nb-card-body class="card-body">
          <!-- Some code here -->
        </nb-card-body>
      </nb-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

This is the platforms.component:
HTML; I've created a div for the dynamic component container;
<div>
  <ng-container #dynamicComponentContainer></ng-container>
</div>

TS
import { TutorialService } from './services/tutorial.service';
import { TutorialPlatformComponent } from "src/app/shared/components/tutorial-platform/tutorial-platform.component";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";


@Component({
    selector: 'app-platforms',
    templateUrl: './platforms.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./platforms.component.scss']
})
export class PlatformsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer!: ViewContainerRef;
    private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    constructor(        
        private tutorialService: TutorialService
    ) {  console.log('--> PlatformsComponent constructor called');}    

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('ngAfterViewInit called in PlatformsComponent');
        this.subscription.add(
            this.tutorialService.displayFakePlatform$.subscribe(() => {
                console.log('displayFakePlatform$ triggered');
                this.displayTutorialPlatform();
            })
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log('ngOnDestroy called in PlatformsComponent');
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    
    displayTutorialPlatform() {
        // Create the component
        this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(TutorialPlatformComponent);
        console.log("dynamicComponentContainer created");
    }

Once seen all the code, here is the log I get when I execute:
Fake Platform has been displayed.               dyd.component.ts:295:20
entering fakePlatformDisplay()...               tutorial.service.ts:49:12
-----------<>----------.                        dyd.component.ts:297:20
--> PlatformsComponent constructor called       platforms.component.ts:78:17
ngAfterViewInit called in PlatformsComponent    platforms.component.ts:81:16

As you can see it reaches the function ngAfterViewInit but it does not do the subscription part why is that happening?
ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('ngAfterViewInit called in PlatformsComponent');
        // ****** IT STOPS HERE ******
        this.subscription.add(
            this.tutorialService.displayFakePlatform$.subscribe(() => {
                console.log('displayFakePlatform$ triggered');
                this.displayTutorialPlatform();
            })
        );
    }


UPDATE
After the changes mentioned by @Naren Murali in her answer it started working, but the component is shown from the beginning instead of just after the 6th step next button is pressed. Now when doing that this new error appears at the console:
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: ''. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook? Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    Angular 5
    NbCardComponent_HostBindings nebular-theme.mjs:133
    Angular 26
    RxJS 6
    Angular 27
    NbButtonComponent_HostBindings nebular-theme.mjs:133
    Angular 5
    DydComponent_ng_template_7_Template dyd.component.html:20
    Angular 17
    draw ngx-joyride.mjs:1362
    drawStep ngx-joyride.mjs:1419
    showStep ngx-joyride.mjs:1491
    tryShowStep ngx-joyride.mjs:1467
    Angular 21
    tryShowStep ngx-joyride.mjs:1465
    Babel 2
    Angular 10

Here is an image of the error log:


Try clearing the container and then creating the component to refresh.
displayTutorialPlatform() {
    // Create the component
    const componentRef = this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(TutorialPlatformComponent);
    componentRef.destroy(); // <- changed here!
    console.log("dynamicComponentContainer created");
}


It could be a timing issue, try using a BehaviourSubject instead.
You are emitted before the subscribe happens.
Fake Platform has been displayed.               dyd.component.ts:295:20
entering fakePlatformDisplay()...               tutorial.service.ts:49:12
-----------<>----------.                        dyd.component.ts:297:20
--> PlatformsComponent constructor called       platforms.component.ts:78:17
ngAfterViewInit called in PlatformsComponent    platforms.component.ts:81:16

Subject does not trigger subscribe method on initial subscription only after the subscribe, emits are recognized, but BehaviourSubject does. So the timing issue might be resolved.
private displayFakePlatformSubject = new BehaviourSubject<string>('');

Then check if the subject has a value then trigger the code.
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit called in PlatformsComponent');
    // ****** IT STOPS HERE ******
    this.subscription.add(
        this.tutorialService.displayFakePlatform$.subscribe((data: string) => {
            if(!data) return;
            console.log('displayFakePlatform$ triggered');
            this.displayTutorialPlatform();
        })
    );
}

Then when you emit change the code to below.
  // Function to listen to an event
  fakePlatformDisplay() {
    console.log('entering fakePlatformDisplay()...');
    this.displayFakePlatformSubject.next('ready');
  }


Thanks for the answer! Now it's triggered okay. But, it doesn't only appear the component when I press the next button in the 6th step the component is there from the beginning

@Linux updated my answer!

I changed as you said but still get the same. Now I have a new error at the console, I updated the question with the mentioned error.

@Linux try this, else share a stackblitz with the issue happening for checking

How can I do that?

@Linux use stackblitz or share the github repo

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
